# Conditional Breakpoints in Intellij for a certain loop iteration

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, whenever I am debugging, and going through a loop, I find myself having to 'Step Over' every iteration until I get to the iteration I desire.

Is there a way to do this and run all the commands that would have happened, instead of just changing the iteration variable to a different value? (which just skips over some iterations of the loop)

For example

```java
for (int i = 0; i < foobar; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Skip to `i`th iteration, but still printing out all the `i` (iterations) along the way.

Comment: Change the iteration value in the console

Comment: That only skips the iterations, it does not go through them. I need something that runs the commands that would have been run.

Comment: There is such thing as conditional breakpoints. Right click the breakpoint and enter condition like `i == 10`

Comment: Is it possible to start on a line before the loop, but still go through the conditions? (start at line 3, and when the for loop is hit, immediately jump to 10th iter.)

Comment: @PeterCho Sounds like you just want 1 unconditional breakpoint before the loop, and 1 conditional breakpoint in the loop...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a concept of [conditional breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint_condition) built in.

[image: conditional breakpoint]

Right click the breakpoint and you'll get a form that you can enter a boolean expression into. The breakpoint will only get hit if it evaluates to true.

With a condition, the breakpoint icon will have a question mark next to the red dot as its icon.